# Raspberry Pi cannot connect to network

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, pi-4, ethernet

Hopefully someone has experienced this issue before but it may be a long shot... I was transferring some large files via smb to an external drive setup on my Raspberry Pi when the connection died. I wasn't able to ssh or remote into the Raspberry Pi so I did a hard reset and since then, it's unable to connect to my network at all. `ifconfig` shows that the `eth0` network is UP, I tried reconnecting the ethernet cable, tried enabling WIFI, and tried restating the switch in which it's connected but it's still unable to connect.

Any ideas on troubleshooting or how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: perhaps there's something in the output of `dmesg` that will help diagnose the issue

Answer (score 0):

Diagnosing a corrupt OS after a crash is difficult, even for experienced users, and rarely successful.

You can try repairing the OS, which should happen automatically on reboot or you could run `fsck` on another Linux system.

Most of us would just restore from a backup.

If you do not have a backup the best option is to perform a fresh install. It is usually possible to recover your files.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it turns out there was actually a problem with the main router (router -> switch -> raspberry pi). For some reason, internet was being output from every port except for the one that was connected to the switch in which the raspberry pi was connected. A simple reboot seemed to solve the issue. Thanks everyone!